# Python/flask/django. I want to make a program similar to discord/teamspeak 3 using django/flask. Question below:

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, flask

Which libraries should be used in order to make voice chats like in discord/teamspeak and how can this be implemented in the program code (by clicking on the voice. chat a person enters it)?

I made text chats only for my messenger, but I didn't find anything for voice chats

Answer (score 0):

You will need to solve the voice chat part of the application by either solving it yourself (creating a voice chat server using e.g. websocket) or by employing a third party.

Example of a build it yourself application can be found here: https://github.com/sspathak/VoiceChat

For example, there is a tutorial by Twilio here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/drop-in-audio-chat-django-react-twilio-programmable-voice